# Problems with threads and graphs

Tags: java, swing, graph, thread-sleep

I am working on a project linked to Prim's algorithm. I want to make yellow some circles in a frame, after 2 seconds to show how the algorithm works. Actually, I have a problem with the code below because, after I compile, it waits 10 seconds (total time of waiting) with a blank frame. After the 10 seconds the frame shows me all resolved. Why did it worked like that and how can I make it work correctly?

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillOval(x[v],y[v],30,30);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("The found edge is "+(u+1)+" ->"+(v+1)+" by price "+min, 320, b);
            b=b+20;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Search on [java swing draw with delay](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+draw+with+delay) and you will find many useful links that explain your problem and possible solutions. The search link that I've given limits the search results to solutions found on this site, and that should be adequate for your purposes. You will earn in these duplicates that you should never use `Thread.sleep` in this way since it puts your entire application to sleep, that instead you will want to use a Swing Timer.

Comment: I encourage you to search first before asking as this sort of question is asked frequently on this site.